# sed bash script is unexpectedly replacing character with space instead of newline

Tags: bash, sed, quoting, newlines, whitespace

Using bash command syntax:

`echo "The*quick*brown*fox"|sed s/*/\\n/g`

I get the desired output:

```
The
quick
brown
fox
```

However in script:

```
IN_TXT="The*quick*brown*fox"
OUT_TXT=$(echo $IN_TXT|sed s/*/\\n/g)
echo $OUT_TXT
```

I get whitespaced:
`The quick brown fox`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: also, it is easier to quote the sed expression instead of escaping special characters.. use `sed 's/*/\n/g'` instead of `sed s/*/\\n/g`

Comment: Please try with `echo "$IN_TXT" | sed 's/*/\n/g'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quoting the variable `OUT_TXT` when you use it with `echo`. This causes the shell to split the variable's value on spaces, tabs and *newlines* into words that are then given as arguments to `echo` (after additionally undergoing filename globbing expansion).  `echo` then outputs those arguments with spaces in-between them.

Quote you variable expansions, always:

```
echo "$OUT_TXT"
```

Also note that you have an issue in `echo $IN_TXT`.  If the expansion of the `IN_TXT` variable isn't quoted as `"$IN_TXT"`, its value would be used as a globbing pattern and would be replaced by any matching filename (test this with `IN_TXT='*'`, for example).

A similar issue is present in your `sed` expression, since it's not properly quoted.

See also:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Also, your `sed` command is better wirtten as `sed 'y/*/\n/'` as standard `sed` simply *can't* insert newlines with the `s///` command (GNU `sed` is an exception).  The `sed` command `y///` *does* know how to change single characters into newlines, regardless of what implementation of `sed` is used.

Or, you could simply use the `tr` command as `tr '*' '\n'`, or a quick variable substitution in the shell:

```
printf '%s\n' "${IN_TXT//\*/ }"
```

or,

```
OUT_TXT=${IN_TXT//\*/ }
printf '%s\n' "$OUT_TXT"
```

Comment: Yep. Double quoting both of those variables did the trick. Cheers!